# Escape ':' in routeProvider in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

My links are like

```
http://localhost/abc/def/index/sort:views/direction:desc/page:5
```

I want to escape the ":" such that the routing will be like

```
.when('/abc/def/index/sort\:view/direction\:desc/page\::pageNo',{
    templateUrl: views+'abc.html',
    controller: 'AbccontrollerCtrl'
});
```

Using '\' does not work.

Comment: Can you explain more what you are trying and where you are getting problem?

Comment: not quite sure but I hope this is what you're looking for : https://plnkr.co/edit/ZuKIFCarnuvQnaJbkKEX?p=preview

Comment: My URL will be like http://localhost/abc/def/index/sort:views/direction:desc/page:5 but I want my controller to read just $routeParams.pageNo and not others. I just have to show my URL like the above